# Removing breaks from timesheet

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have the following code.

```
function hmsToSeconds(hms)
    {
        var times = hms.split(':');
        var hrs = parseInt(times[0]);
        var mins = parseInt(times[1]);
        var secs = parseInt(times[2]);

        return (hrs*3600)+(mins*60)+secs;
    }

    function totalSecondsWorked(start, finish, breaks)
    {
        return hmsToSeconds(finish) - hmsToSeconds(start) - hmsToSeconds(breaks);
    }

    function nearestFullHour(seconds)
    {
        return Math.floor(seconds/3600);
    }

    function checkTime(value)
    {
        var patt = /([0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/;

        if (patt.test(value))
        {
            return value;
        }

        return '00:00:00';
    }

    function calculateDay(day)
    {
        var start = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[startTime]']").val());
        var finish = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[endTime]']").val());
        var breaks = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[breaks]']").val());

        var seconds = totalSecondsWorked(start, finish, breaks);
        var hours = nearestFullHour(seconds);

        $("input[name='"+day+"[total]']").val(hours > 0 ? hours : 0);
        document.getElementById('totalPayableHoursTotal').innerHTML = hours > 0 ? hours : 0;
    }

    $(function(){

        $.each([ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday' , 'saturday', 'sunday' ], function( index, day ) {
            calculateDay(day);
        });

        $(document).on('keyup', 'input.calculate', function(e){
            calculateDay($(this).data('day'));
        });

    });
```

Which does work, but no I need to minus off the breaks and think the Math.floor() method is the cause of the problem, but one I'm not very mathmatical & two only just getting into javascript, so looking for some help.

So for example I type 09:00:00 as the start time then 15:00:00 as the finish time that would be 6 hours, but if I enter 00:30:00 that should return 5.5 hours so i need to get this to work like the example.

I also need to then total up every day for a weekly total, how can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'minus off the breaks'? Could you please provide a specific example of the problem?

Comment: Take away the breaks column, so:

09:00:00 - 15:00:00 (24 hour clock)
with a 30 minute break 00:30:00 would result in 5.5 hours whereas currently it's showing as 6 hours.

Comment: You're correct that the `nearestFullHour` is your problem. You could make a `nearestHalfHour` if you wanted: `Math.floor(seconds/1800)/2;` - that would return things like "3.5 hours"

Comment: @samlev that's the one, thank you so much, problem solved.

Comment: How can I add each day up now then to produce a weekly total like shown in this image http://cl.ly/image/1O2N0I1F1n0J the total at the bottom in this example shown should be 37.5 so how would I get that total?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I've made some changes to your JS code, so you may wish to diff to see all of them):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function hmsToSeconds(hms) {
            var times = hms.split(':');
            var hrs = parseInt(times[0]);
            var mins = parseInt(times[1]);
            var secs = parseInt(times[2]);
            return (hrs*3600)+(mins*60)+secs;
        }
        function totalSecondsWorked(day) {
            var start = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[startTime]']").val());
            var finish = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[endTime]']").val());
            var breaks = checkTime($("input[name='"+day+"[breaks]']").val());

            return hmsToSeconds(finish) - hmsToSeconds(start) - hmsToSeconds(breaks);
        }
        function nearestFullHour(seconds) {
            return Math.floor(seconds/3600);
            return seconds;
        }
        function secondsToHms(seconds_param) {
            var raw_hours = seconds_param / 3600;
            var hours = parseInt(raw_hours);
            var raw_minutes = (raw_hours - hours) * 60;
            var minutes = parseInt(raw_minutes);
            var seconds = (Math.round((raw_minutes - minutes) * 100) / 100) * 60;

            if (seconds > 59) {
                do {
                    ++minutes;
                    seconds -= 60;
                } while (seconds > 59);
            }

            var hours_str = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours.toString() : hours.toString();
            var minutes_str = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString();
            var seconds_str = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds.toString() : seconds.toString();
            return hours_str + ':' + minutes_str + ':' + seconds_str;
        }
        function checkTime(value) {
            var patt = /([0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/;
            if (patt.test(value)) {
                return value;
            }
            return '00:00:00';
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var total_seconds = 0;
            $.each([ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday' , 'saturday', 'sunday' ], function( index, day ) {
                var seconds = totalSecondsWorked(day);
                total_seconds += seconds;
                $("input[name='"+day+"[total]']").val(seconds > 0 ? secondsToHms(seconds) : 0);
            });
            document.getElementById('totalPayableHoursTotal').innerHTML = total_seconds > 0 ? secondsToHms(total_seconds) : 0;
            $('#calculate').click(function () {
                var total_seconds = 0;
                $.each([ 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday' , 'saturday', 'sunday' ], function( index, day ) {
                    var seconds = totalSecondsWorked(day);
                    total_seconds += seconds;
                    $("input[name='"+day+"[total]']").val(seconds > 0 ? secondsToHms(seconds) : 0);
                });
                document.getElementById('totalPayableHoursTotal').innerHTML = total_seconds > 0 ? secondsToHms(total_seconds) : 0;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h5>Monday</h5>
        Start: <input name="monday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="monday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="monday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="monday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Tuesday</h5>
        Start: <input name="tuesday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="tuesday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="tuesday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="tuesday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Wednesday</h5>
        Start: <input name="wednesday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="wednesday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="wednesday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="wednesday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Thursday</h5>
        Start: <input name="thursday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="thursday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="thursday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="thursday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Friday</h5>
        Start: <input name="friday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="friday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="friday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="friday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Saturday</h5>
        Start: <input name="saturday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="saturday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="saturday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="saturday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <h5>Sunday</h5>
        Start: <input name="sunday[startTime]" type="text" value="09:00:00" />
        End: <input name="sunday[endTime]" type="text" value="15:00:00" />
        Breaks: <input name="sunday[breaks]" type="text" value="00:30:00" />
        Total: <input name="sunday[total]" type="text" value="" />
        <br />
        <input id="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" />
        <div id="totalPayableHoursTotal"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also you may test it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88nuwfs0/4/).

Make sure to test thoroughly before running to production, although I did my testing, but I'm not really a QA person.. ^)